# Does anyone know how to beautify git branches with sub directories?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash

When I run `git branch -a` a massive list of local and remote branches is returned. An example output is:

```
  remotes/origin/Production/v1
  remotes/origin/Production/v2
  remotes/origin/QA/v1
  remotes/origin/QA/v2
  remotes/origin/design/sort
  remotes/origin/design/charts
  remotes/origin/etc/task1
  remotes/origin/etc/task2
```

Is there a way to beautify this in the terminal for massive repos? Or is there any other way to list all branches in a more structured way? A preferable output format would be:

```
Production
├── v1
├── v2
QA
├── v1
├── v2
design
├── sort
├── charts
etc
├── task1
├── task2
```

Comment: Preemptively-- if someone recommends using `tree .git/refs`, that won't work if your refs are packed after a `git gc` run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do this on the command line. However, a UI for Git like [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) could work well for you, as it does for me. In the screenshot below, you can see the folder-like structure of how SourceTree organizes branches in sub-folders. You can clearly see how large numbers of branches are hidden under the `bugfix`, `feature`, and `fix` folders, while the `release` folder of branches has been expanded.

[image: SourceTree branch folder organization]